# How to draw this path?

Tags: c#, xaml, path, styles, shapes

I´m trying to get the exact shape or path from the following image.

I was using Visual Studio but it still makes me difficult to write point by point.

I guess there´s another way or software to draw this better, and a little hand about how would be those points in xaml.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first part of your question, here's an example (you can play with the Stroke & Fill Color obviously to get what you want.)

WPF Sample:

```
<Path StrokeThickness="1.0" Stroke="#fffbaf3f" StrokeMiterLimit="1.0" Fill="#fff7931d" Data="F1 M 0.500,0.500 L 0.500,30.500 L 23.340,30.500 L 29.750,40.000 L 36.750,30.500 L 120.500,30.500 L 120.500,0.500 L 0.500,0.500 Z"/>
```

As for the second part to your question, personally I primarily use Adobe Illustrator with a XAML Exporter plugin made by Mike Swanson (http://www.mikeswanson.com/XAMLExport)

Or, I also quite often use Microsoft Expression Blend for all sorts of related things. Hope this helps.